# Windows 10 no keyboard, mouse in Windows, works in UEFI, etc

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, keyboard, mouse

Odd problem. I have a Lenovo ThinkCentre Tiny M700 in the Tiny-In-One 24 display (likely not relevant, but just in case). Today at boot (and consequent reboots) when the login splash page comes up, I have no keyboard or mouse. I can get into the UEFI settings and they work there; after forcing a hard reset it brought up the startup repair (cannot fix), then in command prompt keyboard and mouse work. However, they do not work in the GUI, even in safe mode.

I remoted into the machine and I can control it fine. We did a restore to the last restore point and still no keyboard or mouse. In Device Mgr I they show as having issues. Tried updating driver, removed the devices, rebooted, etc. Tried another kbd and mouse. Go go. Driver errors every time.

Ran CHKDSK /R, Ran SFC /Scannow. Same problem also exits in safe mode.

Device manager shows "No compatible drivers" for all the affected items including the keyboard and mouse. Anyone have a solution for missing drivers for usb keyboards and mice?

Comment: forgot: once sfc finishes I'll try safe mode

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I ran SFC, DISM, CHKDSK again from boot/repair media, then restored to the same restore point I had tried in the past. Finally it worked. I did get some permission errors in odd places (registry in a mostly-unrelated process, and in Program Files). It's working.